# Java mail timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot, email

I am using spring-boot-starter-mail to send an email from my backend.   I have these values copied from my hosting provider:

**application.properties**:

```
 email.username=sender@me.us <== used in the "FROM"
    spring.mail.host=mail.4da.us <== dont' think this is needed?
    spring.mail.port=465
    spring.mail.username=sender@me.us
    spring.mail.password=<My login password>
    spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp
    spring.mail.properties.mail.host=mail.4da.us
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=465
    spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
```

And then I build the email as:

```
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
 @Autowired
 private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
...
try {
  SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();
  // Setting up necessary details
  mailMessage.setFrom(EMAIL_USERNAME);
  mailMessage.setReplyTo(EMAIL_USERNAME);
  mailMessage.setSentDate(new Date());
  mailMessage.setTo(emailRequest.getEmailAddress());
  mailMessage.setText(buildMessage(emailRequest));
  mailMessage.setSubject(SUBJECT);

  // Sending the mail
  logger.info("sending email {}", mailMessage);
  javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);

catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to send email. Error message: " + e.getMessage());
}
...
```

After several seconds I get the exception:

> Failed to send email. Error message: Mail server connection failed;
> nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting
> from SMTP host: mail.4da.us, port: 465, response: [EOF]. Failed
> messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Got bad greeting from SMTP
> host: mail.4da.us, port: 465, response: [EOF]

I have confirmed the email settings with my host.  In fact, I have that same email account on my computer to send/receive from - so I am confident its good there.  I have also tried prepending "smpt" to mail.me.us but that failed immediately as not found.

UPDATE:
I didn't put the real stmp point here for security concerns, guess that doesn't really matter?  Anyway, I tried via telnet:

```
telnet mail.4da.us 465
```

> Trying 35.215.124.126... Connected to mail.4da.us. Escape character is
> '^]'.

So it does appear to connect outside Java

I also added some application.properties to timeout quicker and actually got a slightly difference exception.

```
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=3000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
```

> Failed to send email. Error message: Mail server connection failed;
> nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading
> response; nested exception is: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read
> timed out. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception
> reading response;

Comment: `Host mail.me.us not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)`

Comment: Double check the connection settings. Sounds like there is no mail server running on that port. Try with `telnet mail.me.us 465` to check. Turn on debug logging in Javamail to see what commands it tries and what the server says. Check if there is a firewall messing with your traffic.

Comment: I should have mentioned for security sake I didn't put my real stmp endpoint here.  Updating with real endpoint

Comment: Well those are public addresses. As long as no creds are in your post, it's all good

Comment: Try adding `spring.mail.properties.smtp.starttls.enable=true` Hoping that spring.mail.properties.smtp.user and spring.mail.properties.smtp.password are there

Comment: I added spring.mail.properties.smtp.starttls.enable=true and I still appear to timeout as I am getting the same exception have a couple of minutes of waiting.  Yes, the username and password are in the properties file.  And since I am getting a timeout and not an authentication exception I assume this means they are being loaded.

Comment: The telnet command shows that no mail server is listening on that port. Compare to `telnet mail.4da.us 25`, and enter `ehlo me` to see how the server advertises what it offers. I'd try to switch my Javamail configuration to use port 25 instead of 465.

Comment: Difficult to debug this without an actual account. Your MUA might be doing something that your mail API hasn't got the smarts to do on its own. Try 587. It *is* listening on that port.

Comment: Thank you @g00se it turned out to be port 587 that worked!  I appreciate the help Robert also, the telnet suggestion was helpful.